# cell.contentView.constraints.count = 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

Use Storyboard create constraints for cell but `cell.contentView.constraints.count` is `0`.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];
    cell.fd_enforceFrameLayout = NO;// why equals to 0
    cell.item = self.items[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%ld", cell.contentView.constraints.count);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit better? What are you trying to do exactly? What is the result you want? What is the result you are getting?

Comment: ok! I use storyboard create Dynamic cell,and I add some constraints for the custom cell,now I want to use the constraints,the result of  "cell.contentView.constraints.count" is 0  , but the result should be the count of constrains I add;  oh Forgive my poor English !

Comment: You should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentfier:forIndexPath` rather than the version you are using. The `forIndexPath` version will have a size class associated with it which may be your problem. Also check cell is actually not nil.

Comment: If you want to access a few of the constraints, rather than search in code, CTRL drag from the constraint from IB into your cell header and create an IBOutlet. You can then change the constraint in code using the IBOutlet.

Comment: thanks! I will try it

Comment: that's no useful.but I found the reason is size classes,if I not chose the size classes ,the result is 15,if I choose the size classes the result is 0.how to solve the question with size classes

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `forIndexPath` version of `dequeuReusableCellWithIdentfier`. The non indexPath version returns a cell which has no size class as the cell is not part of the table. The `forIndexPath` version does return a cell which has a size class as it inherits it from its containing table.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.fd_enforceFrameLayout = NO;// why equals to 0
    cell.item = self.items[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%ld", cell.contentView.constraints.count);
    return cell;
}
```

The NSLog should then print the `count` value which matches the number of constraints for the size class you are running under. It would be worth you printing the size class out as part of your debug.